# passport.authenticate callback not being executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I m developing a backend with nodejs v8.7.0,
for the authentication im using passport and local passport , i worked with this before and everything going well , but now i dont know what is the problem, well this is my code :

my strategy :

```js
var passport = require('passport')
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
    passport.use('local', new LocalStrategy({
            usernameField: 'email'
        },
        function (email, password, done) {
            User.findOne({
                email: email,
                is_admin: false
            }, function (err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err)
                }
                // Return if user not found in database
                if (!user) {
                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'User not found'
                    })
                }
                // Return if password is wrong
                if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'Password is wrong'
                    })
                }
                // If credentials are correct, return the user object
                return done(null, user)
            })
        }
    ))
```

and here is where the call happen :

```js
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    try {
        passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
            console.log('here xx')

            var token;
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return res.status(401).json(err);
            }
            // If a user is found
            if (user) {
                console.log('here')

                token = user.generateJwt();
                return res.status(200).json({
                    "token": token
                });
            } else {
                // If user is not found
                res.status(401).json(info);
            }
        })

    } catch (reason) {
        res.status(501).json({
            message: reason.message
        })
    }
})
```

the problem is that im getting nothing like the message from console.log or anything like errors, its not executing the callback from passport.authenticate.... by the way everything like registering new users and everything is working well
anyone can help please ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Passport should be used as `middleware`.  Use it like this in your route:

`router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), (req, res) => { })`

Inside your route, you'll have access to `req.user`

If you're not using as middleware, you can use a callback.  But you need to pass in `req`, `res` and `next`.

For example:

```
passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {

})(req, res, next)
```

Here's a full example, note this is not using middleware as in this case you're defining custom messages and need to use a callback to get the info.

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {      
        if (err) {
            return res.status(401).json(err);
        }
        if (user) {
            const token = user.generateJwt();
            return res.status(200).json({
                "token": token
            });
        } else {
            res.status(401).json(info);
        }
    })(req, res, next)
})
```

Comment: can you clarify a little more please about what i have to change when i use it as middleware ?

Comment: You need to change your implementation in your route.  Remove all of the passport code within your `router.post` and and include it as I referenced above.  I'll include full code.

Comment: @ettayebmohamed I updated my answer to use the callback method, this will work better for you since you are defining a custom message within passport and want that in your route.

Comment: why you calling it 2 times ? using it as a middleware will ask for the use of serialise and deserialise and sessions... i dont want all of this, i just want to make it work the simple way with calling it inside the callback function :(

Comment: Just a copy and paste mistake.  I removed it as middleware.  The key here is you need to be executing the function by passing `(req, res, next)` to at the end of your `passport.authenticate`

Comment: i added (req, res) to the end of passport.authenticate and everything is working well now and i just returned back to my old code and i find that i didnt copy (req, res)  .im so sad man thank youu

Answer (score 2):

When you use `passport.authenticate` as a callback, it is your application's responsibility to establish a session (by calling `req.login()`) and send a response.

Here is link to `passport.js` documentation that could help:
http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/